# AngularJS Read More Directive - adding extra one space when loading more text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on read more and read less functionality of HTML text shown on tables and grids. My project is created using AngularJs and Html as front end.

To implement read more/less, I have used : AngularJS Read More Directive - without jQuery dependency - https://github.com/ismarslomic/angular-read-more

It works fine, but some time when I try to load more using **Read More..** option then it load complete paragraph by adding extra one space in spelling. Lets take examplein given codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWyEma

In this if I set limit as :

```
$scope.limit = 52;
```

As the limit can be any to show less text. But when I click on read more then it load example text as :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing **e  lit**.
>
> *Original is :* Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

As I can not check the space or ending of any sentence and then set limit as per that point. My limit should be same for all screens.

How can I overcome the issue of adding extra space in the text when loading more?

Comment: its is an open issue in their github repository 
https://github.com/ismarslomic/angular-read-more/issues/26

Comment: this one has a PR.. can be helpful https://github.com/ismarslomic/angular-read-more/issues/20